# onreadystatechange in a loop, readystate changes too late

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, onreadystatechange

I issue in a loop a total of eight xmlhttprequests to a Google map server and process the json objects the server returns to retrieve the zip codes. The code works fine if the xmlhttprequests are synchronous. Since I'm supposed to use asynchronous requests, I'm trying to convert the code to asynchronous. It doesn't work.

I use two alerts to monitor myZip. When the code is run, the second alert, right above the return, runs eight times and shows myZip as null or undefined and that is what is returned. Then the first alert runs eight times and gives the desired zip code, too late, unfortunately. It seems to me the readystate doesn't change until too late.

How should I modify the code so it will return the zip code, not null? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+city+state+"&sensor=false";

req.open("GET", url,true);

var myZip;

req.onreadystatechange = function()
{ 
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        (function(data){
            var myObj = eval( '(' + data + ')' );
            if(myObj.status=="OK"){    
                  for(i=0; i <myObj.results[0].address_components.length; i++){
                  if(myObj.results[0].address_components[i].types=="postal_code"){
                  myZip=myObj.results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                  alert('zip is '+myZip);
                  }
               }
            }    
            else    
            {
            alert("Error: returned status code "+req.status+" "+req.statusText);
            }
        })(req.responseText);
    }
}
req.send();
alert(myZip);
return myZip;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use the same object(req) a couple of times and will be overwritten on each loop.

So use separate objects for every requests or start a new request if the last one is finished.

How exactly you can do this  I cannot say without knowing what req is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. req is just a standard xmlhttprequest (req = new XMLHttpRequest();) I believe the req is not overwritten because I get eight alerts (the first alert is called eight times, displaying the desired zip code.)

Comment: Sorry, if you believe that everything is OK, I cant help you. It's also magic how you get around same-origin-policy with a standard xmlhttprequest.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use a callback instead of return statement, or you should run this as Stratified JavaScript: http://stratifiedjs.org.
Then you can write it in a synchronous fashion, like you kind of did, even though it will NOT block your browser.